# Sign of the $n$-form

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

Consider $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ 1-form in a manifold. Take $\omega = \alpha_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha_n$. Now, fixed $i,j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and $\sigma$ a permutation such that $\sigma(k) = k$ for $k \neq i,j$ and $\sigma(i) = j$ and $\sigma(j) = i$, is this formula correct?
$$
\alpha_{\sigma(1)}\wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha_{\sigma(n)} = (-1)^{i+j} \alpha_1 \wedge \cdots\wedge\alpha_n
$$

Comment: No it is not. It should be $\varepsilon(\sigma)$ instead of $(-1)^{i+j}$, where $\varepsilon\colon \mathfrak{S}_n \to \{\pm 1\}$ is the signature morphism ($-1$ in the case of a transposition)

Comment: @Didier You should post this as an answer ...

Comment: @ArcticChar No, it is always $-1$ since this $\sigma$ is a transposition.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: $dx^3\wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^1 = - dx^1\wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3 \neq (-1)^{1+3} dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3$ in $\Bbb R^3$.
What is true is that for $\sigma\in \mathfrak{S}_n$, $\alpha^{\sigma(1)}\wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha^{\sigma(n)} = \varepsilon(\sigma) \alpha^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha^n$, where $\varepsilon(\sigma)$ is the signature of $\sigma$.
In your specific question, $\sigma$ is just the transposition $(ij)$, which has signature $-1$.

Comment: Oh! Nice, and if we simple put $\alpha_i$ in the $j$-th position? What is the signature? $(-1)^{i+j+1}$, right?

Comment: @JulianDoyle I let you find out what's the signature of the corresponding transposition, this is a straightforward application of my answer